# Eclipse highlight all changes since revision X

Tags: eclipse, svn, ide

I'm trying to highlight all changes in the code since a particular revision (we use svn). It looks like I can use Show Annotations on a particular file, but is there a way (either natively in Eclipse or with a plugin) to hihglight all changes since revision X?

Comment: Do you mean all changes in your complete workspace?

Answer (score 0):

You can display the changes between revisions of a project/file/folder from the history view.

1. Right Click on the project/file/folder and select Team->Show History.
2. In the History View click on the start revision.
3. CTRL click on the end revision.  (In your case the latest)
4. Right click on the head revision and select Compare...
5. Click OK in the Compare window.

Eclipse should open a new tab in your editor displaying the differences between the selected revisions.

Comment: that's not quite what I was looking for, but thanks for the answer. I am trying to find a way to basically use the full eclipse editor, not just the compare window with just the changed lines highlighted. This is useful for things like code reviews when using the jupiter plugin.